# Tensor product of polynomial algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. I am trying to prove that the $R$-algebras $R[x,y]$ and $R[x]\otimes R[y]$ are isomorphic. In the course of that I remembered the well known relation $R/I\otimes R/J\simeq R/(I+J)$. I argued that $R[x,y]/(x)\simeq R[y]$ (I believe it is true) and the same for $R[x]$ and I found that $$R[y]\otimes R[x]\simeq\frac{R[x,y]}{(x)}\otimes \frac{R[x,y]}{(y)}\simeq \frac{R[x,y]}{(x)+(y)}$$ but the last ring seems (to me) to be $R$, so certainly something is wrong. What?

Comment: For the last isomorphism to hold, you would need the tensor product to be taken over $R[x,y]$.  However, in this case (even though it is not stated explicitly in your question), the tensor product is taken over $R$.

Comment: Thank you so much, it would have taken ages to me to notice that. You can write your comment as an answer to close the topic. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The isomorphism between $R[x,y]$ and $R[x]\otimes_R R[y]$ holds because the tensor product is taken over $R$.  In the last isomorphism in your post, the tensor product has to be taken over $R[x,y]$.  Therefore, it does not contradict the claim.

Answer (score 5):

One can practically "feel" the iso because of the bases. Indeed $R[X]$ ($X$ is a set of variables) is free over $R$, with basis $(X^{\alpha})_{\alpha\in \mathbb{N}^{(X)}}$. Then, the linear mapping $x^p\otimes y^q\to x^p.y^q$ maps basis to basis. Moreover it is compatible with products and neutrals.